# TypeScript service.ts to connect Postgresql database

Tags: angular, typescript, postgresql

I wrote a typescript.ts script, which can retrieve data from the postgresql database.
I don't know why this code doesn't work in the service.ts file? How to customize this script to work in the service.ts module?

```
import { Pool, Client } from 'pg';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';


const pool = new Pool({
    host: 'edited',
    user: environment.user,
    password: environment.password,
    database: 'price',
    port: 5432,
    ssl: true
})

const client = pool

client.connect(err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    else { queryDatabase(); }
});

function queryDatabase() {

    console.log(`Running query to PostgreSQL server: `);

    const query = 'SELECT * FROM testtable;';

    client.query(query)
        .then(res => {
            const rows = res.rows;

            rows.map(row => {
                console.log(`Read: ${JSON.stringify(row)}`);
            });

            process.exit();
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
}
```

Comment: You don't say _how_ it doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Which part doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Angular is front-end technology that has no native way to access your database.**

If you have an Angular application and want to query your postgres database, the easiest and correct way to do that might be to build a small node server or with any other framework to directly access the data stored in postgres database and then serve them to your Angular app.

Trying to query